# Scraping a web page based on fonts and font-size

Tags: html, fonts, web-scraping

HTML text scraping is doable with various libraries that can be found in the web . I am trying to parse the biggest heading (title) of a web page - only that - from various HTML pages.

I am trying to automatically detect the main title of the item from several hundred pages (it can be a product page or an article page etc.). It would be great if there was a way to make my parsing decision based on the font and the font size of the text that is available in the web page. Since the main title is almost always the text with the biggest font in the web page, this information can give a me a lot of insight about where to find the title.

So the questions is, is there any way that this can be accomplished?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to find the highest "<hn>" element? I.e. If there's a `<h1></h1>` with some text in between, use that. Otherwise try h2, h3, ...

Comment: Unfortunately it is not always in the <h*> tag and even if it is sometimes there are various other elements on top of the actual product/artice name/title. Edited the questions should not have mention header which can be confused with <header>

Comment: The problem with size-based detection is that there are so many sources the size is calculated from. You'd probably need an actual HTML renderer, and read the effective size from it. Also, sometimes the heading isn't the biggest text on a website.

Comment: are there any image processing libraries which might detect segments from the webpage? I know some not-free ones but nothing free as far as I know.

Comment: even an approximation would be useful. So maybe you can give me the first places to look for that might have that information and how to do that. Is there a way to get the css and parse that for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suppose* you could do it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/854z2de0/), but this is a very resource intensive task because you iterate over **all** html elements in the body.

```
var text,
    size = 0;

$("body, body *").each(function() {
    var f_size = parseInt($(this).css("fontSize"));
    if (size<f_size) {
        text = $(this).text();
        size = f_size;
    }
    console.log(this.tagName + " " + f_size);
});
```

Comment: that actually is working quite fine after I filter out unnecessary parts of the html.